# Detects url in plain text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to detect url in  text in Javascript,can you tell me what is wrong in this function?

```
function findUrl() {
    var text = document.getElementById("content");
    var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;

    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
    }); 
}

findUrl();
```

Comment: A simpler regex could be : /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g

Comment: Your second `[...]` part in the regex is missing a quantifier. I can very much recommend regex101.com to do some tests before actually using a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

`text` is not a string but a `DOMElement`. Maybe you want:

```
var text = document.getElementById("content").value; // if #content is an <input>
// or
var text = document.getElementById("content").textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prob simplify it to:

```
function findUrl() {
    var text = document.getElementById("content").textContent;
    var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/\S+)/gi;

    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    return `<a href="${url}">${url}</a>`;
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Does not work in Safari